# Natsort not working as it should

Tags: php

I got a script that shows a gallery, the images in the gallery are pulled from a directory using scandir (a function). I'm using natsort to order the images in a numerical way (all images only have numbers, example: 1.jpg 12.jpg 13.jpg etc etc).

Natsort should order them but instead the images are not sorted at all.

My code:

```
function scan_dir($dir) {
    $ignored = array('.', '..', '.svn', '.htaccess','index.html');

    $files = array();
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
        if (in_array($file, $ignored)) continue;
        $files[$file] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
    }

    natsort($files);
    $files = array_keys($files);

    return ($files) ? $files : false; 
}
    if(is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_intern/SNM/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/') != FALSE){
        foreach(scan_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_intern/web/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/') as $entry) {
            $gallery .= '
             <a href="/_intern/web/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/'.$entry.'">
                  <img class="galleryimgs" title="'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'" alt="'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'" src="/_intern/web/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/'.$entry.'" />
             </a>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '';    
    }
    echo $gallery;
```

Comment: `natsort` sorts by value, not by key.

Comment: @apokryfos Alright, do you know where I should place natsort then?

Comment: `ksort($files,SORT_NATURAL)` instead of `natsort($files)`

Comment: Thanks! @apokryfos write it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is:

`natsort($files)` sorts by value, not by key. It is in reality equivalent to `sort($files,SORT_NATURAL)`

If you want to sort keys (which is what you need in your case) you need to use:

```
ksort($files,SORT_NATURAL)
```

A full list of PHP sort functions can be found in the manual pages at http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php